# How to get list of commits that touched a given line of code (git)

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I want to cherry pick from one branch to another, but they diverged strongly.
How can I get list of commits that modified a given part of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 common solutions:

- [git blame](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/git-blame.html)

> Annotates each line in the given file with information from the revision which last modified the line. Optionally, start annotating from the given revision.
>
> The command can also limit the range of lines annotated.

- [git bisect](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html)

to quickly determine what commit did introduce a specific change.

See also "[Using git to find first introduction of token on a specific line of a file…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863393/using-git-to-find-first-introduction-of-token-on-a-specific-line-of-a-file)"