# Search all Git branches for a keyword

Tags: git

I swear I wrote a test called "heartbeatTest" or "heartbeatRouteTest" in one of the branches of a Git repository.

But I can't find it in any of the branches. Is there a way to do a global search with Git to find a matching phrase in any branch for a particular local/remote repository?

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
git log -G"$regex" --all
```

or

```
git log -S"string" --all
```

<sup><sup>[git log reference](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_options)</sup></sup>

which search all current history for commits that change lines (`-G`) or change the number of lines (`-S`) containing a match.  There are plenty of options to alter `git log`'s selection of starting points to walk through history.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Git grep](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep)

```
git grep heartbeat $(git rev-list --all)
```

You could be a little more specific with:

```
git grep heartbeat.*Test $(git rev-list --all)
```

Here is a nice article with more examples of using Git grep: *[Search a Git repository like a ninja](http://travisjeffery.com/b/2012/02/search-a-git-repo-like-a-ninja/)*

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292391/is-it-possible-to-perform-a-grep-search-in-all-the-branches-of-git-project