# How can I search RubySpec on GitHub?

Tags: ruby, github, rubyspec

I was trying to find the specifications for `String#split` in RubySpec on GitHub. (Turns out to be `core/string/split_spec.rb`.)

If I try [searching on ruby/rubyspec](https://github.com/ruby/rubyspec/search?q=string%20split&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93), I get told

> Sorry, forked repositories are not currently searchable.
>
> You could try searching the [parent repository](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/search?q=string%20split&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Trying the linked search on the parent repository `rubyspec/rubyspec`, I get

> We couldn’t find any code matching 'string split'
>
> You could try an [advanced search](https://github.com/search/advanced?q=string%20split&repository=rubyspec&type=Code&user_id=rubyspec&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

However, the [advanced search](https://github.com/search/advanced?q=string%20split&repository=rubyspec&type=Code&user_id=rubyspec&utf8=%E2%9C%93) doesn't seem to have any ability to search the [archive branch](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/tree/archive) of `rubyspec/rubyspec`, which has actual code in it (the master branch just has a `README` file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm that search, on GitHub, is limited on `master` branches only of non-forked repo.
See "[How to search for a commit message in GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28493853/6309)".

You would need to make a copy (not a fork) of that repo and publish it on GitHub to use GitHub search.
Or you can perform a [grep search on all branches in a local clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15293283/6309).