# How can I check out multiple branches that match a prefix and run commands

Tags: git

I have a git repo which has multiple releases branches.

What I want to do is create a script that will list all release branches that match a pattern, check out each of these branches in turn and run a git merge from master and push it back to remote.

Is there anyway to do that without me typing the branch name manually?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292391/is-it-possible-to-perform-a-grep-search-in-all-the-branches-of-git-project

Answer (score 0):

```
for branch in `git branch --list prefix\*`; do
    git checkout $branch &&
    git merge master &&
    git push origin $branch || exit 1
done
```

PS. For a script add `set -e` at the start and you can remove `&&` and `|| exit 1`.