# Git grep over all commits in all braches and open up in a pager?

Tags: git, vim, pager

I am able to grep over all branches, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15293283/164148), but I want to open the results in a pager such as vim. Failing:

```
git grep -Ovim <regexp> $(git rev-list --all)
```

which works without the need to go over all commits with `$(git rev-list --all)`.

**How can I grep over all commits in all branches and open up the results in a pager such as vim?**

Comment: You want to open the grep result in vim or you want to open the matched files in vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the `open file in pager` function, you cannot across branches. It works only on the worktree.

But if you want to open the grep result in vim, it is easy:

```
git grep ... $(git rev-list --all)|vim -
```

You may want to tweak your grep option to suppress the color output.

Comment: Why the last one? Git tools pretty much know how to use `isatty()` and actually use it.