# Git Grep sometimes makes terminal stop showing typed commands

Tags: linux, git, terminal, grep

I am searching for the word `STATIC_ASSERT` in all branches in my Git repo using this command, which I modified [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41898410/4561887):

```bash
time git branch -a --color=never | sed -e 's/[ \*]*//' \
    | grep -v -e '\->' -e '^remotes' \
    | xargs -n 1 -P "$(nproc)" git grep -I "STATIC_ASSERT"
```

If I remove `-P "$(nproc)"` then it works fine but takes 1.8 seconds.

If I add that back in, I get the exact same output, but it uses multiple processes in parallel and takes only 0.4 seconds! But, then I get [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/171449/327339) where the terminal stops showing typed commands, and I have to follow [my instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238357/327339) to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and type `reset` to get the terminal back to normal.

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Note: it may not be repeatable in your repo. I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a hint in [the top answer on that question](https://askubuntu.com/a/172747/301745): editors. [Git uses a pager](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_core_pager), which is sort of like an editor, so if you disable it, the issue goes away.

```
git --no-pager grep ...
```

If your output is long and you want to add back the pager, you can do it manually, for example:

```
git --no-pager grep --color=always ... | less
```

(`--color=always` is because `git` normally disables color when not outputting directly to a terminal.)

Comment: This would be rather unusual for git. Disable colours because the output is not a terminal, but keep  the pager?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI If the output is not a terminal, git doesn't use a pager. I think you're mixing up two different things. But funny that you mention it, you can actually do `... | cat` to get the same effect as `--no-pager`.

Comment: Oh, thank goodness this is it! I never would have found it. Thank you. This now works fine with `--no-pager` added: `time git branch -a --color=never | sed -e 's/[ \*]*//' | grep -v -e '\->' -e '^remotes' | xargs -n 1 -P "$(nproc)" git --no-pager grep -I "STATIC_ASSERT"`

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I was able to make this answer: [All about searching (via `grep` or similar) in your git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77917015/4561887). I was completely stumped otherwise.