# Cross Search in all repositories and branches in Azure Devops Repos

Tags: azure, azure-devops, branch, azure-repos

Azure has very nice function to facilitate cross search through all repositories:

[image]

I have noticed that after I did search for a keyword which was in one of the branches it was not found. How can I cross search also through all the branches from all repositories?

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following PowerShell scripts to update the searchable branches via REST API.

```
$token = "{PAT}"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$url="https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/policy/Configurations/{Configuration ID}?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
$body = @'
{
    "type": {
        "id": "0517f88d-4ec5-4343-9d26-9930ebd53069"
    },
    "isBlocking": false,
    "isEnabled": false,
    "settings": {
        "scope": [
            {
                "repositoryId": "{Your repo ID}"
            }
        ],
        "searchBranches": [
            "refs/heads/Branch1",
            "refs/heads/branch2",
            "refs/heads/Branch3"
        ]
    }
}
'@
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method PUT -Headers $head -Body $body -ContentType application/json
```

- PAT: Personal access token
- Org name: Your organization name
- Project name: Your project name
- Configuration ID: The configuration ID. You can get it by running REST API [Configurations - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) or check the network trace when editing the searchable branch from UI.
- repositoryId: The ID of your repo. You can get it when you run REST API Configurations - List. Or you can see it from the URL when you edit searchable branches from UI.
- searchBranches: The branches you want to search. Set it as `[ ]` if you want to remove all branches except the default beanch.

Comment: @Z this is an interesting option, but as I said in the other comment: In my usual workflow I am creating new branch and removing it after I finish my work. So adding a branch to the index everytime I create one is additional work I would like to avoid.  As well as choosing which one should be added and which removed. But I give you a +1 for very functional script.

Comment: @fascynacja, I understand your concern. The current issue is not that searchable branches cannot be added automatically, but that there is no trigger when a new branch is created or deleted. Therefore, we can't automatically run scripts to update searchable branches. Checking the webhook and logic app, I don't find such a trigger. If you want such a trigger, you can submit a feature request from https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion. Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback.

Comment: To make it clearer for others to know about the scripts that can update searchable branches and why it currently cannot be run automatically when a branch is created or deleted, it's suggested that you could accept my answer according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Besides, if you submit such a feature request, it would be better if you can share here. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that people with postfix MSFT always force me to accept their answers. I do not like it. I will accept an answer which solves my problem, if not yours then maybe someone else will find the solution.

Comment: Anyhow I have created a request as you suggested but I am hoping in the meantime someone will suggest some solution.

Answer (score 1):

When searching for code in Azure DevOps, it is possible to search fast because the default branch of each repository has been indexed.

You can extend which branches are indexed, and therefore will be included in the search by navigating to `Settings -> Repositories -> {{ choose repository }} -> Searchable branches`, allowing you add a maximum of 5 more searchable branches per repository. It may take several hours your your newly added branches to become searchable however, as the indexing may take some time. See [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/functional-code-search?view=azure-devops#search-git-projects-and-repositories).

[image]

However, it appears you can still only choose one branch to search at a time. If this doesn't meet your needs, I would recommend searching for help on "how to search for code across all git branches", and use a method outside of what Azure DevOps offers. Here is an [example stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151311/using-git-how-could-i-search-for-a-string-across-all-branches) that may be closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: @fascynacja, as mentioned by Scott, currently, it supports adding up to 5 more searchable branches. If you still want more searchable branches in Azure DevOps, you can submit a feature request to ask for supporting more branches from https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion.

Comment: That is interesting option. In my usual workflow I am creating new branch and removing it after I finish my work. Sometimes the span life of a branch would be 2 weeks only. So adding a branch to the index everytime  I create one is additional work I would like to avoid. Is there any mechanism which would add the branches automatically when they are created and remove when they are removed?

Comment: @fascynacja, I haven't found a default feature that can do it automatically.  As a workaround, you can run REST API to update the searchable branch. See my answer for the detailed info.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a feature request to enable cross search through all branches:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cross-Search-in-all-repositories-and-bra/10573114