# When did git introduce the "--local" switch for git config command?

Tags: git, git-config

In what git version became the `git config --local` option available, and where can I read more about it?

I thought that not providing `--global` will automatically assume that it's a local config variable. Why was this new option necessary?

Comment: As to why it's necessary, one can speculate that it is for filtering, e.g. used with --list

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816134/finding-a-git-commit-that-introduced-a-string-in-any-branch

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the git sources are maintained in git, we can find the revision that introduced the `--local` option:

```
commit 57210a678a8bedd222bf4478eeb0a664d9dd5369
Author: Sverre Rabbelier <srabbelier@gmail.com>
Date:   2010-08-03 20:59:23 -0500

    config: add --local option

    This is a shorthand similar to --system but instead uses
    the config file of the current repository.
```

It appears that this change first appeared in release 1.7.4 which came out in late 2010 or so.

As far as I can tell from a quick look at the source code (`builtin/config.h`) and man page, the default is local *unless* certain environment variables are set, particularly `$GIT_CONFIG`.  The `--local` option explicitly overrides any environment variable settings.

See [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17290282/827263) for more information on the semantics of `--local` (the documentation was updated after I originally posted this answer).

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks Keith.

Answer (score 7):

Note that the description for that `--local` option has only recently (June 2013, three years later) been updated:

[Commit 560d4b86abc547dfb10b116ab99c800d68ae8849](https://github.com/git/git/commit/560d4b86abc547dfb10b116ab99c800d68ae8849):

> config: Add description of `--local` option
>
> It was missed in the option list while mentioned from the general description.
>   Add it for completeness.

The description is now:

```
--local::
```

> - For **writing options**: write to the repository `.git/config` file.
>     This is the default behavior.
> - For **reading options**: **read only from the repository `.git/config` rather than from all available files**.