# Getting the total diff made by all commits matching a string

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log

When our development team use Git we always include the case number we are working with in the commit message.

When we code review a particular case, we would like to a way to show all the changes made by all the commits with a message that contains the case number.

The commits are not necessarily consecutive (but they are all on the same "branch").

Also, we don't just want the diffs produced by each individual commit, rather we would like the "total" diff. Say that file has been changed by multiple matching commits (the changes might even overlap), then we would like just one diff output for that file, containing all the changes made by all the commits.

As an aside, this could easily be acheived on SVN using TortoiseSVN, where you could search for the case number, and select all the resulting files. That would produce such a "total" diff for every file concerned.

How would you achieve that in Git? 
(If a script, it has to be runnable on Windows, preferrably in PowerShell) (Using Git Extensions or TortoiseGit is ok)

Comment: I can't answer your question directly but the best workflow with git is generally to use one branch per feature(I guess "case" in your question), and merge once it's done into your master branch. Then the branch *is* the changes for that "case" and nothing else. Branches are really really cheap in git so this is the common way to work.

Comment: Agreed, however we do not always create branches for features, so a solution to the stated problem would be great. For instance a feature might be "finished" and merged into master, only to be resuscitated by a bug report or a new requirement, creating additional commits to the same feature. (And yes requirements should not change, but tell that to our requirement analyst)

Comment: Also, as a Git proponent myself, I find it a bit embarrassing that this feature is so readily available in SVN, but seems impossible to achieve in Git.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816134/git-finding-a-commit-that-introduced-a-string) using

`git log -Ssearchstring --source --all`

Comment: No, that does not work for the following reasons: 1) I am not searching for something introduced in a commit, I am matching strings in the commit message, so `--grep` is much closer than `-S` 2) I am not looking for a log of changes, I am looking for *diffs*. 3) Adding `-p` does not achieve what I want since I want the diffs unified for each file, not diffs for the individual commits.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood you first.