# Determine when a line was modified in a file

Tags: git, blame

In a git repository used by many people, I found some code code I'm interested in, but it's not fully fleshed out.

I have no way of knowing whether this is a recent or old change, so I hesitate to just browse back through all commits on the file.

Is it possible find when the line of code appeared in the repository so I can talk to the original person who posted it?

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816134/git-finding-a-commit-that-introduced-a-string. Also take a look at git blame: http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/07/git-tip-of-week-assigning-blame.html

Comment: git blame will give you the last person who commited a particular line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the perfect case for `git blame`.

As per its [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html)

> Annotates each line in the given file with information from the revision which last modified the line. Optionally, start annotating from the given revision.

You can use it like follows

```
git blame -- filename
```

Optionally (advisable, I'd say) you can output the result on a file

```
git blame -- filename > blame.out
```

and open the file with any editor supporting the `git blame` syntax. I use for instance Sublime Text 2.

Other tips from comments:

```
git gui blame -- filename
```

will start a basic gui interface, which can be helpful.

Also

```
git blame -L 42,+1 -- filename
```

will show only line 42, in case you are interested in a specific line.

Comment: `git gui blame -- filename` is also useful.

Comment: If you know the line number you're after, you can also use `git blame -L <lineno>,+1 -- filename`, and it will show just the single line.

Comment: Just what I needed. The ironic part: I was the one who added the line in question!

Comment: @Benmj ironic indeed! I integrated the good suggestions by jszakmeister in my answer.