# How to find all commits with a specific string on the insertions and deletions?

Tags: git, github

I need to perform a specific kind of log using git.

I would like to know how can I find all commits ids that have insertions or deletions using a specific string (like 'my_table', for example) from a beginning date to an end one.

Is possible show the author and the lines changed on the context of the commits who matchs the  query?

Someone know how can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816134/git-finding-a-commit-that-introduced-a-string

Comment: @PherricOxide, yes I see. But after my edit I think I need a little more of that question offers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `git log -S"string"` This will show you all commits where the number of occurances of "string" changed. If you want to see the patch itself add the `-p` flag or `--patch` flag.

You an change the output of the log with `--pretty`, the author can be show using '%an'

```
git log -S"string" -p --pretty="%an"
```

For more options and information have a look at tho man pages. They are also available online (https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html).

Comment: Thx a lot. This works, but I needed to change a little the question. Do you know how can I do this?

Comment: @GarouDan `git log -S"string" -p` that will also show the author and the commit sha. If you want only the author, the commit sha run and the context `git -p -S"string" --pretty="%H %an"`. It is all there in the man pages https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html. There are a lot more options you may find interesting.

Comment: I think I missread change that to `--pretty="%an"` if you only want the author.

Answer (score 1):

To query the repository's  *patch* contents, use

`git log -S<string-pattern> --diff-filter AD`.

Optionally add `--pickaxe-regex` when using `-S` to enable regular expression patterns.

Alternatively, to search the *commit messages* for a specific string, use

`git log --grep="<message-pattern>" --diff-filter AD`

The `--diff-filter AD` limits results to only commits where the files were *Added* or *Deleted*.