# How to find out in which commit a particular code was added?

Tags: git, git-commit

I want to find out in which commit did I add the code given below:

```
if (getListView().getChildCount() == 0)
                getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Run `git blame` on the file. It'll show you the commit ID, the date and time, and who committed it- for each line. Then just copy out the commit identifier and you can use it in `git log <commit>` or `git show <commit>`.

For example, I've got a file, called test.txt, with lines added on different commits:

```
$ cat test.txt
First line.
Second line.
```

Running the `git blame`:

```
$ git blame test.txt
^410c3dd (Leigh 2013-11-09 12:00:00 1) First line.
2365eb7d (Leigh 2013-11-09 12:00:10 2) Second line.
```

The first bit is the commit ID, then name, then date, time, time zone, and finally the line number and line contents.

Comment: The problem is that this only shows when those files where last changed and not when they were added.

Comment: @ensonic This answer may be interesting if that's the case (e.g. the line was moved, or a whitespace change): http://stackoverflow.com/a/5816177/812680

Comment: Useful additional is to grep the results `git blame test.txt | grep 'First line'`

Comment: That does not answer the OP's question. We had a problem where all our repository went through a "re-indent code" change, to shrink tabs from 4 spaces to 2. From that moment on, all git blame will always reveal the guy who re-indented the code - not the one who introduced it. git log -S does the trick.

Answer (score 145):

```
git log -S searchTerm
```

gives you the commits in which the search term was introduced.

Comment: I think that's the best answer as the OP wanted to search for some code (not file) added.

Comment: I agree - I had a problem where all the repository went through a "re-indent code" session, to shrink tabs from 4 spaces to 2. From that moment on, all git blame will always reveal the guy who re-indented the code - not the one who introduced it. git log -S does the trick.

Comment: Just to mention, searchTerm should be in string quotes. Something like `git log -S "createUserFunction()"`

Comment: I use this command and I got different results when executed against different main branches (for example UAT vs PROD). Why is that?

Answer (score 55):

There is something quicker than issuing a blame on the full file.  If the line is `${lineno}` and the file is `${filename}` you can:

```
git blame -L ${lineno},${lineno} ${filename}
```

Example:

```
git blame -L 2,2 test.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question - unless that line of code was never changed. It will reveal who is the user who last changed these lines of code. Not the one who introduced them. git log -S, though, will. However, useful technique...

Comment: With out a doubt, the right solution!

Answer (score 43):

```
git log -S "mention here line of code" [file-path]
```

For example:

```
git log -S "First line" test.txt
```

Providing the file name with its path is obvious because, most of the time, we want to know who introduced a particular code segment in a particular file.

Comment: Excuse me, I can't get it - what should be put in the "mention here line of code". the Line-number? the actual line contents? a Text to search for? Can you please be clearer ?

Comment: OK. I used it, and I marvelled at the results. this A LIFE SAVER. really. In our rather clumsy and lousy corporate repository, some wise-guy decided to change the tab spacing fro 4 to 2 over 1.2M lines of code. Of course from that moment on - git blame is meaningless - because every damn line has changed by that same nasty commit of re-indenting the sources. So - this really gave me the rope i needed - to find who "invented" a line of code, and not the last person to have changed it. THANK YOU. Big hand.

Comment: Thanks for appreciating.

Comment: In the Linux terminal it required single quotes for the line of code: `git log -S 'some code' path/to/file.c`

Comment: This was a lifesaver! Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to do this on github.com? Would save the hassle of downloading the repository.

Answer (score 3):

If code is being maintained in `Git` repository and `intellij` IDE along with Git plugin is being used to browse the code then i have found the following way very intuitive:

1. Open the file in `intellij`
2. Go to context menu -> Git -> Annotate.
3. New window will appear where each line in new window tells who made that line commit.

Following screenshots are for the references:

[image]

Comment: Very useful. I don't get a new window, but I do get dates and contributor names next to the line numbers in the usual file editor pane, which if clicked on show the specific commit. Thanks Anshul!