# `fatal: ambiguous argument`… `unknown revision or path` error, but I'm searching for a path in the code

Tags: git, zsh

I want to find the first instance of `$PREFIX/opt/rubies` in [this file](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/blob/master/share/chruby/chruby.sh).

I'm using the suggestion from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5816177/335847):

`git log -S <whatever> --source --all`

So my line is:

```
git log -S "PREFIX/opt/rubies" --source --all
```

but I get this error message:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'PREFIX/opt/rubies': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

I also have an alias set up:

```
alias.search log --format='%C(yellow)%h %an %ad%C(reset)%n%w(72,1,2)%s' -S
```

So I try:

```
git search "PREFIX/opt/rubies"
```

Same error. I thought it might be because the slashes needed escaping, nope.

The version of Git I'm using is 1.7.1, because I broke my newer Git the other day and haven't got round to fixing it. I'm running the commands via zsh, version 4.3.9.

Any help or insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are literally getting

```
ambiguous argument 'PREFIX/opt/rubies'
```

, have you checked that

```
PREFIX
```

is defined is in the root of your development directory (same place as *.git*)? It looks from the file that *$PREFIX* is a variable in the code in the file.

Comment: Since I removed the `$` sign in front of it and wrapped it in quotes, why would the shell interpolate it? It's just an uppercase string literal. And why is git thinking a string literal passed as an argument to `-S` should be treated as a path?