# Search for string in one file in all branches

Tags: git

Is it possible to Git **grep** a string in **one file** in **all branches**?

I know I made a change to a particular file; I just can't find which branch I did it on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding a Git commit that introduced a string in any branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816134/finding-a-git-commit-that-introduced-a-string-in-any-branch)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to ElpieKay for providing this nice little gem:

```
git grep a_string $(git rev-parse --all -- target_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
git stash
git branch | while read line
do
echo branch:$line
git checkout $line -- target_file
grep a_string target_file
done
git stash pop
```

Have a try.

Comment: While I can see this working, it feels inefficient.  Anybody got anything better?  I was hoping for a command line flag.

Comment: @MichaelArrison try `git grep a_string $(git rev-list --all -- target_file)`

Comment: @MichaelArrison `git branch --merged blob_sha1` can list which branch(es) the blob_sha1 is from.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work.  I tried: "git grep opacity $(git rev-list --all -- css/main.css)" for example and got a list back that included matches from other files.

Comment: Sorry, use `rev-parse` instead of `rev-list` please.

Comment: That's better.  rev-parse worked.  Feel free to make this the answer and I'll give it a check.

Comment: What shell? [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)?