# Find first existence of a line of code in Git

Tags: git, git-blame

I am trying to trace a piece of code (just a single line) to it's commit.

Using blame only points me to a commit where this line in question was moved as a part of an extract method style refactoring.

What techniques can I use to get to the commit were that particular text existed in the codebase for the first time?

Comment: Does `-C` and/or `-M` to `git blame` work for you? `git blame` is showing you the first existence, but you want to ignore moves: but what counts as a move? It's a bit fuzzy, which is why `git blame` doesn't do it by default, I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: finding a commit that introduced a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816134/git-finding-a-commit-that-introduced-a-string) and also [Using git to find first introduction of token on a specific line of a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863393/using-git-to-find-first-introduction-of-token-on-a-specific-line-of-a-file).

Comment: Recursively blaming the file is the manual/normal way (blame, che kout parent commit, blame etc)

Comment: @AD7six `git log -S <line>` or `git log -G <regex>` is much more efficient, and less work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5816177/456814) to [git: finding a commit that introduced a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816134/git-finding-a-commit-that-introduced-a-string), you can simply use

```
git log -S <line>
# or
git log -G <regex>
```

to find the first occurrence of a line of code in a repository.

From the [official Linux kernel Git documentation for `log`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html):

> ```
> -S<string>
> ```
>
> Look for differences that introduce or remove an instance of `<string>`. Note that this is different than the string simply appearing in diff output; see the *pickaxe* entry in [gitdiffcore(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitdiffcore.html) for more details.
>
> ```
> -G<regex>
> ```
>
> Look for differences whose added or removed line matches the given `<regex>`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do `git log -p filename` and search (pressing <kbd>/</kbd>) for the given text.

This way you notice changes of that line and you can continue searching for a (slightly) different text if the text changed in the past.

Comment: You can ***eventually*** find the first occurrence of a line this way, but it can be very inefficient and time-consuming. Using `git log -S <line>` or `git log -G <regex>` is much faster and efficient.

Comment: Yes, other options might be faster, but this way you have the whole context of all commits for that file.

Answer (score -1):

I would probably settle for:

```shell-script
function allcommits { 
    git rev-list --reverse HEAD
}


for i in `allcommits` ;do  
    git co -f $i 2>/dev/null ; 
    echo commit:$i ;
    git grep -q 'that line of code' && break
done
```

You check out every commit starting with the first one, and scan all files in each step, until you find a match.

Comment: Don't forget to commit, because git checkout --force will kill your changes.

Comment: `git log` supports the `--reverse` option...